# Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page. error showing on submit customer register magento 2.3 on localhost

Tags: magento2

when i try to create customer on localhost. Its getting error"Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."

magento version:-2.3
Theme:- luma
Php:-7.2
Xammp, Windows....

Answer (score 0):

magento 2 have some problems with location
try with 127.0.0.1